# How can I map data to a postcode on a map (Google Maps)?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-maps, maps

I'm not sure on the question title here so please suggest an edit if you have a better idea.

I am building a web application using JavaScript and PHP; it's an internal sort-of dashboard.

I have written a database query that gives results results that look like:

I have written a PHP script that connects to our database and returns results in JSON format like:

```
[  
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"BA14 6RU",
        "ORDERS":"1"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"BH11 8NX",
        "ORDERS":"20"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"BH12 4NU",
        "ORDERS":"2"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"BH12 4PA",
        "ORDERS":"27"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"BH15 4PT",
        "ORDERS":"10"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"BH17 7BD",
        "ORDERS":"17"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"BS15 4TA",
        "ORDERS":"18"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"BS3 2SU",
        "ORDERS":"2"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"BS3 5QY",
        "ORDERS":"1"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"BS30 8XT",
        "ORDERS":"2"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"C04 9HT",
        "ORDERS":"14"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"CF33 4AH",
        "ORDERS":"5"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"CF33 6BJ",
        "ORDERS":"17"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"CF33 6BN",
        "ORDERS":"12"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"CF44 6DA",
        "ORDERS":"3"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"CF63 2BE",
        "ORDERS":"4"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"CF83 8DW",
        "ORDERS":"8"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"CM16 6NR",
        "ORDERS":"8"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"CM5 9JH",
        "ORDERS":"6"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"CM8 3HP",
        "ORDERS":"1"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"CM8 3UW",
        "ORDERS":"15"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"CO3 8ND",
        "ORDERS":"4"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"CO4 5HW",
        "ORDERS":"4"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"DN11 8SP",
        "ORDERS":"31"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"DN41 8DG",
        "ORDERS":"22"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"E15 3LX",
        "ORDERS":"2"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"FN14 6LH",
        "ORDERS":"5"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"GU15 2QU",
        "ORDERS":"16"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"GU15 2QW",
        "ORDERS":"4"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"GU35 9QF",
        "ORDERS":"10"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"GU51 3RN",
        "ORDERS":"10"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"HA2 9EF",
        "ORDERS":"7"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"HA4 0JS",
        "ORDERS":"2"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"HP11 1EL",
        "ORDERS":"3"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"HP6 6JQ",
        "ORDERS":"6"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"IP7 6RL",
        "ORDERS":"8"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"LE6 0JL",
        "ORDERS":"17"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"LN6 3RY",
        "ORDERS":"9"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"ME12 1LY",
        "ORDERS":"1"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"N17 9LJ",
        "ORDERS":"5"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"NG24 2DZ",
        "ORDERS":"3"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"NG31 9SE",
        "ORDERS":"1"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"NN1 2JW",
        "ORDERS":"3"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"NN11 4HU",
        "ORDERS":"5"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"NP11 4SB",
        "ORDERS":"11"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"NP26 3TF",
        "ORDERS":"1"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"NP44 1TY",
        "ORDERS":"13"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"NR6 6AG",
        "ORDERS":"1"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"NR6 6NN",
        "ORDERS":"6"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"PE1 5YB",
        "ORDERS":"3"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"PE7 3EL",
        "ORDERS":"15"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"PO13 0FG",
        "ORDERS":"2"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"PO14 1FD",
        "ORDERS":"4"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"PO14 1NP",
        "ORDERS":"4"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"PO16 8TT",
        "ORDERS":"24"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"PO4 8PY",
        "ORDERS":"5"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"PO6 1SQ",
        "ORDERS":"11"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"RG1 8EQ",
        "ORDERS":"22"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"RG1 8LG",
        "ORDERS":"4"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"RG12 1RL",
        "ORDERS":"3"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"RG2 OHG",
        "ORDERS":"8"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"RG24 7AT",
        "ORDERS":"5"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"RG24 8NA",
        "ORDERS":"1"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"RG7 1PQ",
        "ORDERS":"1"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"RG7 4AZ",
        "ORDERS":"1"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"RG9 5LA",
        "ORDERS":"1"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"RH4 1QT",
        "ORDERS":"7"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"S015 3AS",
        "ORDERS":"3"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"S030 2PA",
        "ORDERS":"3"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"SA1 3JA",
        "ORDERS":"2"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"SA10 6RR",
        "ORDERS":"2"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"SA10 7DN",
        "ORDERS":"10"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"SA12 6LN",
        "ORDERS":"1"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"SA14 6RB",
        "ORDERS":"11"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"SA14 8LQ",
        "ORDERS":"2"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"SA18 2HX",
        "ORDERS":"2"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"SA18 3SJ",
        "ORDERS":"3"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"SA4 9DW",
        "ORDERS":"8"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"SA4 9WF",
        "ORDERS":"6"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"SA48 8LT",
        "ORDERS":"6"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"SA5 4DL",
        "ORDERS":"1"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"SA5 4SF",
        "ORDERS":"3"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"SA5 8JY",
        "ORDERS":"2"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"SA6 5BQ",
        "ORDERS":"2"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"SA6 8QR",
        "ORDERS":"26"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"SA6 8RF",
        "ORDERS":"13"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"SA7 0AE",
        "ORDERS":"2"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"SA7 9FU",
        "ORDERS":"1"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"SA7 9QY",
        "ORDERS":"3"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"SA8 4EZ",
        "ORDERS":"5"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"SN2 2NP",
        "ORDERS":"34"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"SN2 2PQ",
        "ORDERS":"2"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"SO30 2PA",
        "ORDERS":"17"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"SO32 2QE",
        "ORDERS":"5"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"SS13 1DJ",
        "ORDERS":"3"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"SS14 3DB",
        "ORDERS":"3"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"SS2 5RN",
        "ORDERS":"38"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"SS6 7UY",
        "ORDERS":"7"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"TW17 8RX",
        "ORDERS":"21"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":"WD1 8SR",
        "ORDERS":"2"
    },
    {  
        "POSTCODE":null,
        "ORDERS":"35"
    }
]
```

I need to display a map of the United Kingdom (technically I would only ever need England and Wales) and show circles where we are delivering today.

The circle would need to be big or small depending on the number of orders that we're delivering to that postcode compared to the other postcodes and also would need to contain the number of orders.

Is there something out there that I could use to do this sort-of thing?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called a heat map (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-heatmap).  Plenty of good plug-ins for google maps to do that for you.  You could also try a MarkerCluster (http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2009/04/markerclusterer-solution-to-too-many.html).

A simplier solution is to use a custom marker icon that's a circle, and just change it's size based on how many deliveries there are for that postcode.

Comment: These seem to mostly take latitudes and longitudes whereas I have postcodes.

Comment: http://www.freemaptools.com/download-uk-postcode-lat-lng.htm  Download one of those, put it in your database.  Use a join and get your lat/long to pass to google map api.